Impossible to find movie with a madman on a motorcycle
I saw this movie in Italian, so I don't know if in English it's the same (many times the Italian dubbing is totally different, in Hellraiser for example the cenobite say "This is not for your eyes", in Italian it's a totally different translation "Grazie, ma adesso devi guardare").
This movie from 1990-95 is about a madman who runs with a big motorcycle, and in a desert country (a country near the desert) tries to kidnap and rape a girl and her boyfriend(!) with the intention to sod..ize them both (!!).
Many time he scream "nutri la bestia!". If in the original English language it's identical to the Italian dub, the translation is "Feed the beast!"
Release year: 1990-94
Format: probably TV movie
Country: USA
Other info: rare,trash

That sounds interesting (I think!). '-)

If you like trash movie,is a must,is very rare i think,i see it on a regional italian tv about 15-20 years ago ..and i not record it :(

Trash is an understatement: Meet Billy Badd (AKA Motor Psycho) from 1992. From a synopsis online:

Action packed story follows two college bound teens, Frankie and Zoey, on a frightful odyssey through the heart of California's Mojave Desert. While driving across country, the young lovers quickly encounter Bill Badd, a shotgun wielding motorcyclist who forces them into a series of deadly road games. The couple is quickly plunged into a life and death survival race on the Motor Psycho's demented road to hell....

Billy voices his desire to, er, have both Frankie and Zoey, and after they dent his beloved bike he utters in Razzy-worthy gravitas: "FEED THE BEAST!" You can see it here around 2:28:



